# I keep getting the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, discord, replit

I am using python here.

when I run my code for a discord bot I am making with replit, I get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

I am making a discord bot with this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-discord-bot-with-python/

code:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {Funni bot B)}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$IHaveNoBobux'):
        await message.channel.send('haha sucks to be you B)')
   
    if message.content.startswith('$GiveMeFreeBobuxNow'):
        await message.channel.send('no stupid noob B)')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

can someone help me fix this error? I have a small brain and no close to no python so some things might need a lot of explaning. :/

this is the full console when I run the code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 21, in 
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
File "/home/runner/go-away-this-isnt-for-you/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
return future.result()
File "/home/runner/go-away-this-isnt-for-you/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/runner/go-away-this-isnt-for-you/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
File "/home/runner/go-away-this-isnt-for-you/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

I also have an env called "env" which has the following inside it:

```
TOKEN=[the discord bots token is would be right here but im not going to show it because its the password]
```

Comment: Please share the complete error message and stack trace, which should show what line of your code actually leads to the error (apparently somewhere in the imported code). A likely candidate seems to be `os.getenv('TOKEN')` if no `TOKEN` is actually defined in the environment the code is run in

Comment: okay I changed the post in it to include absolutely everything in it.

Comment: This is Python.  Trust the error message.  The object that you are trying to call the strip message on is a NoneType object.  Trace back to where you got that object.  Wherever it came from gave you a None return.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps mentioned to get token, it is empty.

**When you created your bot user on Discord, you copied a token. Now we are going to create a .env file to store the token. If you are running your code locally, you don't need the .env file. Just replace os.getenv('TOKEN') with the token.**

Answer (score 0):

The file is supposed to be called `.env` not just `env`.
Assuming that's what it is already named and it still doesn't work for you, you can instead [use a json file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-json-file-using-python/) if you need to upload it to remote repository (don't forget to add the json file in .gitignore).

```py
import json
import discord 

client = discord.Client()

env_json = json.loads("env.json")
key = env_json['TOKEN']

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.username}')

client.run(key)
```

Comment: `json.loads` takes a string, you're thinking about `json.load` which takes a filename